# Escaping the slash in r does not work

Tags: regex, r

I have read that if you want to insert a backslash in a string you need to escape it:

```
a <- "\\"
```

The problem is that if I do that I get two slashes in my string!

```
> a <- "\\"
> a
[1] "\\"
```

How can I get just one single backslash in my string?

Comment: The output of `print` is not the same as the actual thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually get two backslashes--that's actually a single character :-)

Test it out:

```
a <- "\\"
nchar(a)
# [1] 1
cat(a)
# \
```